# how can I deploy vue js to my apache server? I'm using centos 8 Linux

Tags: apache, vue.js, centos8

I want to deploy my VUE JS project to the **apache** server. I'm using **Centos** 8 OS. Step I have done but failed:

- build
- the project
- upload the dist folder
- browse the folder name with IP.

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried so far? What does "failed" mean?

Comment: I failed to run the project. I could not browse my project. Showing error in the console and home page showing blank.

Comment: Please share more details such that others can help

Comment: okay, look, I have developed a project with the Vue js and finish in the localhost. every time I run the project I have run the command as npm run serve. now if want to deploy the project in an IP like 123.778.xxx.67. and want to browse the project in the browser like 123.778.xxx.67/project. how can I do that or what is the process to run the project in that IP(123.778.xxx.67)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase, thanks, and good news I solved it on my own what I wanted.